# R Roxygen link to parent function

Tags: r, inheritance, roxygen

Consider a base package `XYZ`, written by someone else, which has a function `ABC`, I want to extend the functionality of `ABC` in my new (NOT XYZ) package via the following method.

```
ABC <- function(...){
  ##INSERT EXTRA WORK.

  ##CALL THE BASE METHOD
  XYZ::ABC(...)
}
```

Now I want to document my new function `ABC` (via Roxygen), creating a link to the parent function for reference purposes.

`\code{\link{XYZ::ABC}}` does not work, no function cannot be found.

`\link{ABC}` creates a link to a list of possible candiate Rd files,

How do I create the hyperlink **DIRECTLY** to the **BASE** function.

Comment: `@importsFrom XYZ ABC`, no?

Comment: `\code{\link[XYZ]{ABC}}`

Comment: Thats it. Put it in an answer and Ill tick it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\code{\link[XYZ]{ABC}}`

This is briefly documented in the [Cross-references](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Cross_002dreferences) section of Writing R Extensions:

> There are two other forms of optional argument specified as \link[pkg]{foo} and \link[pkg:bar]{foo} to link to the package pkg, to files foo.html and bar.html respectively.