# How to `\link{}` to a specific section of an Rd file with Roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

Say I want to link to the "Details" section of my documentation for function `foo`, what do I do?  `\link{foo:Details}` doesn't appear to work, so what is the right command?

Comment: Linking to an individual section is not supported by R.

Comment: You could request this feature on r-devel http://www.r-project.org/mail.html, and see if any core members are sympathetic.

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014218/r-roxygen-link-to-parent-function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\linkSections{}` to link to sections of an `Rd file`.

```
\linkSections{foo}
```

will link to the section of the foo documentation that you are currently viewing.

If you want to link to a specific section, you can use

```
\linkSections{foo,Details}
```

to link to the *Details* section of the foo documentation.